# JavaScript can't receive child stream one line at a time

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process, spawn

When using `child_process.spawn` in Node, it spawns a child process and automatically create stdin, stdout and stderr streams to interact with the child.

```
const child = require('child_process');
const subProcess = child.spawn("python", ["myPythonScript.py"])

subProcess.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + data); 
});
```

I thus imlemented this in my project but the thing is that the subprocess actually write on the output stream only when the buffer reach a certain size. And not when the buffer is set with data (whatever the size of the data). 
Indeed, i'd like to receive the subprocess output stream directly when it writes it on the output stream, and not when it has filled the whole buffer. any solution ?

**EDIT**: As pointed out by t.888, it should actually be working as i expect. And it actually does if I spawn another subprocess. A c++ one this time. But I don't know why it does not work when I spawn my python script. Actually, the python script sends only big chunks of messages via stdout (probably when the buffer is full)

Comment: According to [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable) the `data` event will provide data whenever it's available. So the buffering might be occurring in the python side of the transaction. _"Attaching a 'data' event listener to a stream that has not been explicitly paused will switch the stream into flowing mode. Data will then be passed as soon as it is available."_

Comment: Indeed, I have just tried to spawn an other process, a c++ one this time, and it works as expected. But I can't figured out why it does not work with my python script as I don't change anything except the process that I spawn.

Comment: maybe because you are running a python command so it's more related to how python handles buffer data than how node do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem yesterday. It was actually due to python itself and not `child_process` function.

I have to do

```
const subProcess = child.spawn("python", ["-u", "myPythonScript.py"])
```

instead of

```
const subProcess = child.spawn("python", ["myPythonScript.py"])
```

indeed, `-u` argument tells python to flush data as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need `readline` instead.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

async function processLineByLine() {
  const fileStream = fs.createReadStream('input.txt');

  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fileStream,
    crlfDelay: Infinity
  });
  // Note: we use the crlfDelay option to recognize all instances of CR LF
  // ('\r\n') in input.txt as a single line break.

  for await (const line of rl) {
    // Each line in input.txt will be successively available here as `line`.
    console.log(`Line from file: ${line}`);
  }
}

processLineByLine();
```

From https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_example_read_file_stream_line_by_line